# How to reverse x axis and make titles bold?

Tags: r, plot, graphics

I am trying to create a plot similar to the one below but with the x axis' reversed so it goes from 100 to -40. I would also like to make the text bold.

This is my code:

```
plot(allEffects(rabbit.model), ylab='Percentage of Rabbits Disturbed', xlab='Time Until Sunset (minutes)', main='')
```

And this is the model (not sure if you need it):

```
rabbit.model<-glm(cbind(nb_distur, nb_non.distur) ~ Power * (scale(Time)), data=rdata[rdata$Power != "0",], family=binomial)
```

Graph
[image]

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You reverse the x-axis if you set `xlim` parameter with the higher value first followed by the lower value. I am not sure which text you need to bold, but you can use `par` to bold the axis labels, axis titles, and main title like so:

```
par(font.axis = 2, font.lab = 2, font.main = 2)
plot(allEffects(rabbit.model), 
     ylab = 'Percentage of Rabbits Disturbed', 
     xlab = 'Time Until Sunset (minutes)', 
     main = '',
     xlim = c(100,-40)
```